# Non equivalent norms : $N_{\infty}(u)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|u_n|\}\text{ and }N_{1}(u)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|u_{n+1}-u_n|\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

On space of bounded sequences $(u_n)$ such that $u_0=0$; I want to show that the two norms are not equivalent : $$N_{\infty}(u)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|u_n|\}\text{ and }N_{1}(u)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|u_{n+1}-u_n|\}$$

I proved that $$N_1(u)\leq 2N_{\infty}(u)$$ In order to show that that these two norms arnt equivalent; I tried to find a sequence $(u^n)$ such that $N_1(u^n)=1$ and $N_{\infty}(u^n)$ goes to infinity, but in vain.

Comment: Try $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}$ for $n\le N$ and $u_n=u_N$ for $n\ge N.$

Comment: When you say what you tried unsuccesfully to show, it looks to me like it should be $n_1(u_n)=1, N_\infty(u_n) \to \infty.$ I mean the $n$'s should be subscripts not powers.

Comment: thank you for your comments the example given by @ryszard szwarc works

Comment: @coffeemath the power is to say that its a sequance of sequences;thanks you

Comment: The example can be made simpler $u_n= \min\{n,N\}.$